# What are the advantages of putting a user into the `docker` group instead of granting her `sudo` access to the host?

Tags: docker

Is there any real advantage in putting a user into the `docker` group rather than granting her `sudo` access to the host?

---

For the long story, I'm writing a tutorial showing how members of the `docker` group can directly interact (ie, without using `sudo`) with the docker server through a Unix domain socket the `dockerd` server is listening on.

However, by granting an unprivileged user the power to create arbitrary containers, it seems that user gains *effective* root access to the host: for example, it becomes quite easy that way to modify the host fs through bind mounts. Or to interact with the kernel via `procfs`/`sysfs`. So what's the point in putting someone into the `docker` group rather than giving that user root access to the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or the user could just [load a nice convenient Docker container that throws them straight into a root shell](https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker.html).

Granting access to the docker socket does indeed virtually guarantee the ability to escalate privileges.

What matters here is declaring your intentions. You put someone in the `docker` group so that they can run containers without needing to run `sudo` for every command all the time. You put someone in `sudoers` when you want them to be able to `sudo` and run any command as root.

If you don't want to give arbitrary people access to the Docker socket, you should almost certainly be using an orchestration system such as OpenShift or Kubernetes.

Comment: You confirmed my understanding @michael and even better, with your first sentence, you gave me the conclusion to my article! Thanks a lot.